# Power BI calculate percentage (divide) using Filter

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I need to show percentage in gauge chart something like this

[image]

I am able to bring 3000 and 37% is the something that needs to be calculated. This guage charts need to show that the data you are looking for/filtering holds 37% of 3000 (i.e. 1110)

Now I need to bring this 37% in gauges chart "Target value" property. I need to write a measure that will divide the filter value of 1110 by 3000 that will bring the value as 37% in a measure. Then I can drag the measure under Target value property.

I have written one measure that essentially does something like this:

[image]

This measure is resulting in value of **1** which is not right.

For example: I have 3 products - A, B & C and I want to find how much Percentage Product A accounts of total of Products A+B+C. In previous example say product A accounts for 1110, product B for 1500 and C for 390

How do I modify my measure so that it gives me the result only for Product A? I know filter function is helpful - not sure how. any new answers are also appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gauge do not support this directly as per my knowledge. But there is work around as given below-

**Step 1:** Create a measure with value 0 to set as Gauge Minimum value and set the type of this measure as Percentage "%".

```
m_min_value = 0
```

**Step 2:** Create a measure with value 1 to set as Gauge Maximum value and set the type of this measure as Percentage "%".

```
m_max_value = 1
```

**Step 3:** Here, I guess you have your measure ready which is showing 37% in your case. If this is the case, just configure your gauge as below-

[image]

**Step 4:** Of "Data Lebels" from the Gauge settings. Take a "CARD" visual with Maximum value which is showing 3000 in your case. Now place the CARD as shown in the below image with disabling CARD background from the settings.

[image]